# What's the shortcut to delete selected layer in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

In my old image editing program, hitting the delete key would delete the currently selected layer. Apparently not so in GIMP - what's GIMP's shortcut to delete the selected layer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. In the GIMP toolbox, select [Edit → Preferences](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-pimping.html#gimp-prefs-dialog).
2. Select Interface from the menu on the left, and then click on the "Configure Keyboard Shortcuts" button.
3. Create a new shortcut for the "Delete Layer" function, I would expand the "Layers" section and click on "Delete Layer".
4. Type in desired shortcut or accelerator. If the accelerator is already assigned to another function, a pop-up box will give you the option to reassign the accelerator to the new function.
5. Once you have assigned all of your desired shortcuts, close the "Configure Keyboard Shortcuts" window. Click on the "Save Keyboard Shortcuts Now" button so that you can immediately begin using your shortcuts.
   The option to "Save keyboard shortcuts on exit" should also be selected. Close the Preferences window when finished.

Gimp references:

- [GIMP Keyboard Shortcuts](http://gimptips.com/articles/gimp-keyboard-shortcuts).
- [Creating Shortcuts to Menu Functions](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-shortcuts.html).

Comment: Sadly it does not seem to allow shortcuts with special keys like Ctrl+Del.

Comment: Is there a shortcut to Hide a layer? I mean, instead of clicking in the eye icon I'd like to use a shortcut to hide the selected layer. Then I could move to the next one easily.

Answer (score 17):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

This is because standard copy-paste shortcuts can be used to interact with layers. So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will copy, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> will paste and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> will cut the active layer.

The <kbd>Del</kbd> key deletes the content of a selection. If there is no selection, the content of the layer is the selection - so <kbd>Del</kbd> deletes the layer's content but preserves the layer itself.

Comment: I'd love this answer. So cool & so easy and simple. THANKS.

Comment: this is very practical. just remember to remove any selection outline before hitting ctrl+x (this is done with shift+ctrl+a   OR    Manu>Select>None)

Comment: I didn't know that one. Very nice trick.

Answer (score 1):

### <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

For Mac running on 10.10.5:

- <kbd>fn</kbd> is the key in the lower left corner
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is the delete key in the upper right corner